# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str with a jsonl file

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonlines

I have a jsonl file, which looks like this:

```
with open('myfile.jsonl', 'r') as f:
    dicts = json.load(f)

# it's a list of dictionaries
[{'date': '2018-12-11',
  'base_currency': 'EUR',
  'target_currency': 'USD',
  'exchange_rate': 1.1379},
 {'date': '2018-12-11',
  'base_currency': 'EUR',
  'target_currency': 'JPY',
  'exchange_rate': 128.75},..]


# or like this:
with open('myfile.jsonl', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


['[{"date": "2018-12-11", "base_currency": "EUR", "target_currency": "USD", "exchange_rate": 1.1379}, {"date": "2018-12-11", "base_currency": "EUR", "target_currency": "JPY", "exchange_rate": 128.75},..,{..}]\n']
```

then I have this test function:

```
def jsonl_to_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    return sorted(
        [json.loads(l.strip()) for l in lines],
        key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])
    )
```

when I run it, I get this error:

```
jsonl_to_list('myfile.jsonl')

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_40452/1757437785.py in <module>
----> 1 jsonl_to_list('myfile.jsonl')

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_40452/2518347130.py in jsonl_to_list(filename)
      3         lines = f.readlines()
      4 
----> 5     return sorted(
      6         [json.loads(l.strip()) for l in lines],
      7         key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_40452/2518347130.py in <lambda>(x)
      5     return sorted(
      6         [json.loads(l.strip()) for l in lines],
----> 7         key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])
      8     )

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

also, if it helps, previously I saved a list of dictionaries into a jsonl file like this:

```
    # store the new version of the file            
        with open(myfile, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(dicts) + '\n')
```

Can somebody pinpoint my error with this?  I don't have much practice with json. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, opening the file as text and using `f.readlines()` returns a list of 1 element: the full json content as str (a list of dicts)

So in the function

```
def jsonl_to_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    return sorted(
        [json.loads(l.strip()) for l in lines],
        key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])
    )
```

inner variable x is not a single dict, but a list of all your dicts. That's why you got an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when trying to access single dict value on a list of dicts.

A possible solution would be to rebuild your list of dicts after reading lines (actually, the single line of your file).

```
def jsonl_to_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    single_line = lines[0].strip()
    dicts = json.loads(single_line)
    return sorted(
        dicts,
        key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])
    )
```

Or better, directly parse the whole file using `json.load()` then sort the sorted list of dicts

```
def jsonl_to_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        dicts = json.load(f)

    return sorted(
        dicts,
        key=lambda x: (x["target_currency"], x["date"])
    )
```

Comment: thanks, Antwane. I cant change the jsonl_to_list function because it is a test function for my assignment. I can only change how I have created my jsonl file for my assignment to pass the test. from what you said, it seems like I need to convert my list of dictionaries into a single dictionary.

Comment: what should this part, ['[{"date": "2018-12-11",....,{..}]\n'] look like for me to pass?